# Partial transpose of Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheet with this format:

```
+---------+---------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| Field_A | Field_B | Field_C | 24/09/2019 | 25/09/2019 | 26/09/2019 | 27/09/2019 | day... | day... |
+---------+---------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| ValX    | ValY    | ValZ    | Val1       | Val2       | Val3       | Val4       |        |        |
| ValW    | ValY    | ValZ    | Val5       | Val6       | Val7       | Val8       |        |        |
+---------+---------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

First 3 columns are specific fields and all other columns are related to one specific day in a given (and static) range.

I need to *convert* the table in the following format:

```
+---------+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
| Field_A | Field_B | Field_C |    Date    | DateValue |
+---------+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
| ValX    | Valy    | Valz    | 24/09/2019 | Val1      |
| ValX    | Valy    | Valz    | 25/09/2019 | Val2      |
| ValX    | Valy    | Valz    | 26/09/2019 | Val3      |
| ...     |         |         |            |           |
+---------+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Basically, the first 3 columns are gathered as-is, but the day-column in transposed (is even the correct term?) with 2 values:

- The date
- The value in the cell related to date

Is something that can be achieved with formula or do I need to create a bounded AppsScript?

Following a sample Sheet demo: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cprzD96i-4NQ8tieA_nwd8s43yKF-M8Kww4yWNfB6tg/edit#gid=505040170

- In Sheet `Start` you can see the initial data and format, 3 static columns and one column for every da
- In Sheet `End` you can see the output format I'm looking for, the same 3 static columns, but the date and cell value related to date are transposed as a row.

You can see the Formula I used, `TRANSPOSE` for every row, where I select the days for the IV column and one row at a time for the V row.
For the 3 static columns, I replicated the Formula for every instance of the day related to that row.
This is working but requires much manual work to set up every single `TRANSPOSE`. I'm wondering if there is a more automatic way of doing this (except for using AppsScript, in that case, I'm already planning on doing this if not other solutions are available)

Comment: Hello Andreas, I tried with the TRANSPOSE function but it seems to be not suitable for my specific case because part of the value is the column name itself. Here is why I'm asking for help, I do not have much to share.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: I added a demo Sheet as you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(Start!D2:F<>""; "♦"&TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Start!A2:C&"♠");;999^99))&
 TEXT(Start!D1:F1; "dd/mm/yyyy")&"♠"&Start!D2:F; ));;999^99));;999^99); "♦")); "♠")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Can you explain a bit your formula? I can see it's working but I'm trying to understand how it works, starting from the use of `999^99` and `♠ ♦`

Comment: sure, both have no real merit. 999^99 is just "really big number" - problem could come if its too small - in that case, formula won't do what we want it to do (which is join columns into one column). you can try to look at it as "number of rows to proccess your dataset + some backup power". ♦♠ are literally just unique symbols. you can use whatever you wish instead ☺♂♀♪♥♫☼... their purpose is o act as a mark for cutting for SPLIT eg at the end all added symbols are killed by SPLIT.